# Converting non-simple geometries to simple so ArcGIS Pro can display and process them

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

In SQL Server 2016 I'm using GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate to dissolve some polygons into larger ones. Here is a simplified example of my select:

```
select ta.TRANUM, GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate(pp.SHAPE) SHAPE into PARCELS_DERIVED from Parcels pp
left join TAX_RATE_AREA ta
on
pp.Centroid.STIntersects(ta.Shape) = 1
group by ta.TRANUM
```

This works fine in SQL Server but when the resulting data is used in ArcMap it gives geometry errors and can't use the data. I've tracked the problem down to the UnionAggregate creating non-simple geometries:

```
select shape.STIsSimple() IsSimple, shape.IsValidDetailed() IsValid, SHAPE.STGeometryType() SHAPE from T.PARCELS_DERIVED

IsSimple    IsValid SHAPE
1   24400: Valid    MultiPolygon
0   24400: Valid    MultiPolygon
0   24400: Valid    MultiPolygon
0   24400: Valid    MultiPolygon
1   24400: Valid    Polygon
1   24400: Valid    Polygon
1   24400: Valid    MultiPolygon
```

I can add polys that are simple without a problem but if I include Non-simple ones ArcMap throws it's warnings.

Is there anyway to convert/alter the data so that is is usable in ArcGIS Pro?